# Update table A fields using table B columns where table A has a field "_" separated and its corresponding values are there in TABLE B

Tags: oracle, plsql

I have a table ACTIVITY_KEY with the following fields:

```
COL1      COL2    COL3     COL4      COL5     COL6     COl7     
ACt1      A1_B1
ACT2      C1
ACT2      D1_D4
ACT3      A1_F1
```

The fields COL3 to COL7 are empty

Now there is another table KEYDEF with below fields and value:

```
KEY       NAME        VAL
A1        COL4         UI
A1        COL6         2
B1        COL3         98
C1        COL5         N
C1        COL4         00
D1        COL3         1
D1        COL4         PP
D1        COL6         RT
D4        COL5          Y        
D4        COL7         DG 
F1        COL7         NN
F1        COL3         9T
```

I wnat to update table ACTIVITY_KEY for the COL3-COL7 with values from KEYDEF table and it should be like:

```
 COL1      COL2    COL3     COL4      COL5     COL6     COL7
 ACt1      A1_B1    98       UI                  2
 ACT2      C1                00         N
 ACT2      D1_D4     1       PP         Y       RT       DG
 ACT3      A1_F1    9T       UI                 2        NN
```

I am not sure how to do it, can someone help?

Comment: Please show us what you have tried so far and tell us what problems you have with it. Why does `col2` have multiple values separated like that? And can it have more than two?

Comment: If you had a situation where `ACTIVITY_KEY.COL2` was, say, "D4_F1", what would you expect the value of `COL7` to be?

Comment: There wont be a situation like you mentioned Matthew, we have added that as restriction.

Answer (score 1):

Try this merge:

```
merge into ACTIVITY_KEY a
using (
    select
        a.col1,
        a.col2,
        max(k.col3) col3,
        max(k.col4) col4,
        max(k.col5) col5,
        max(k.col6) col6,
        max(k.col7) col7
    from ACTIVITY_KEY a
    left join (
        select *
        from keydef
        pivot (
            max(val) for name in (
                'COL3' as col3,
                'COL4' as col4,
                'COL5' as col5,
                'COL6' as col6,
                'COL7' as col7
            )
        )
    ) k on a.col2 like '%'||k.key||'%'
    group by a.col1, a.col2
) k on (
    a.col1 = k.col1
    and a.col2 = k.col2
)
when matched then update set
    a.col3 = k.col3,
    a.col4 = k.col4,
    a.col5 = k.col5,
    a.col6 = k.col6,
    a.col7 = k.col7;
```

As @Matthew pointed out in the comments, if you can have collisions. the above solution will take the max of the value.

Comment: @gurV- I tried what you suggested but Getting error for this:


Error report -
SQL Error: ORA-00905: missing keyword
00905. 00000 -  "missing keyword"
*Cause:    
*Action:

Comment: A missing "then".. Updated . please try now

Answer (score 0):

Here is a very simple approach.  It assumes you will not have situations where `ACTIVITY_KEY.COL2` is "D4_F1", for example, since that would make the value of `COL7` ambiguous.

```
select col1, col2,
 ( SELECT val FROM keydef d 
   WHERE ak.col2 LIKE '%' || d.key || '%' 
   AND d.name = 'COL3' 
   AND ROWNUM = 1) col3, 
 ( SELECT val FROM keydef d 
   WHERE ak.col2 LIKE '%' || d.key || '%' 
   AND d.name = 'COL4' 
   AND ROWNUM = 1) col4, 
 ( SELECT val FROM keydef d 
   WHERE ak.col2 LIKE '%' || d.key || '%' 
   AND d.name = 'COL5' 
   AND ROWNUM = 1) col5, 
 ( SELECT val FROM keydef d 
   WHERE ak.col2 LIKE '%' || d.key || '%' 
   AND d.name = 'COL6' 
   AND ROWNUM = 1) col6, 
 ( SELECT val FROM keydef d 
   WHERE ak.col2 LIKE '%' || d.key || '%' 
   AND d.name = 'COL7' 
   AND ROWNUM = 1) col7 
 from activity_key ak
```

Once you are satisfied with the `SELECT` (above), you can use it to actually update the columns by placing it a `MERGE` statement.  Like:

```
MERGE TO ACTIVITY_KEY t
USING ( ... SELECT statement above ... ) u
ON ( t.col1 = u.col1 AND t.col2 = u.col2 )  -- assuming COL1+COL2 is unique...
WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE...
```

Comment: The select query looks fine to me but how to update?
How can we add set field names there?

Comment: @Matthhew: getting error

Error report -
SQL Error: ORA-30926: unable to get a stable set of rows in the source tables
30926. 00000 -  "unable to get a stable set of rows in the source tables"
*Cause:    A stable set of rows could not be got because of large dml
           activity or a non-deterministic where clause.
*Action:   Remove any non-deterministic where clauses and reissue the dml.

I added at below:
WHEN MATCHEN THEN UPDATE SET
t.col3 = u.col3,
    t.col4 = u.col4,
    t.col5 = u.col5,
    t.col6 = u.col6,
    t.col7 = u.col7;

Comment: I should have seen from your test data that `COL1` by itself is not unique.  Can you match on `COL1` and `COL2` together?  I've updated my answer to reflect what I mean.

Answer (score 0):

Just a different approach. Hope it helps.

```
MERGE INTO ACTIVITY_KEY C USING
(SELECT col1,
  COL2,
  MAX(COL3) COL3,
  MAX(COL4) COL4,
  MAX(COL5) COL5,
  MAX(COL6) COL6,
  MAX(col7) col7
FROM
  (SELECT B.COL1,
    B.COL2,
    CASE
      WHEN A.name = 'COL3'
      THEN A.VAL
    END COL3,
    CASE
      WHEN A.name = 'COL4'
      THEN A.VAL
    END COL4,
    CASE
      WHEN A.name = 'COL5'
      THEN A.VAL
    END COL5,
    CASE
      WHEN A.name = 'COL6'
      THEN A.VAL
    END COL6,
    CASE
      WHEN A.name = 'COL7'
      THEN A.VAL
    END COL7
  FROM KEYDEFF a,
    activity_key B
  WHERE (a.key=SUBSTR(B.COL2,1,2)
  OR a.key    =SUBSTR(B.COL2,LENGTH(b.col2)-1,LENGTH(b.col2)))
  )
GROUP BY COL1,
  COL2
)B ON (B.COL1 = C.COL1 AND B.COL2 = C.COL2)
WHEN matched THEN
  UPDATE
  SET COL3 = B.COL3,
    COL4   = B.COL4,
    COL5   = B.COL5,
    COL6   = B.COL6,
    col7   = b.col7;
```

Answer (score 0):

This is very simple query to get result.

[image]----------

Comment: put in the code directly instead of putting it as an image and having it's link here.